# can't set zoom level on MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, core-location

i am adding `MKCircleView` to the user annotation like so :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
if (!_MapCentered) {
    **_circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate radius:3000];
    [_map_view addOverlay:_circle];** 
    _MapCentered = YES;
    }
}
```

it will fire once and once the user location has traced, it works well but as you can see the diameter of the circle view is 3000 meters. so now i want the zoom level to fit the `CircleView` like so :

```
        MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 0.270, 0.270);
    [_map_view setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
```

i have changed the delta degrees to other numbers but nothing is changed.
how can i manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your span.
so set your span value in longitudeDelta & latitudeDelta

```
yourRegion.span.longitudeDelta  = 0.004; // set required zoom value 
yourRegion.span.latitudeDelta  = 0.004; // set required zoom value
```

Answer (score 5):

The distance parameters in the `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` function are in *meters* (not degrees).

Also, the meters specify the full width and height so you have to use double the value of the circle's radius.

So it should be:

```
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = 
  MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance
    (mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 6000, 6000);
```

You could also just set the map view's `visibleMapRect` to the `boundingMapRect` of the circle overlay so you don't have to repeat the distance values:

```
mapView.visibleMapRect = _circle.boundingMapRect;
```

Comment: thanks! thats helping. but can you please explain why when i set the region to 3000 3000 i cant see the full circle?

Answer (score 1):

For Google's zoom level i use [this category](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/) for `MKMapView`

Otherwise use Anna's solution