# Zoom in to current location on map

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show the current location of the user on the map and zoom on to it.

I tried as follows:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"Init MapViewController");
        [self initMap];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) initMap
{
    _mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    _mapView.delegate = self;
    _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:_mapView];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation;
    currentLocation.latitude = _mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    currentLocation.longitude= _mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

    [_mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
}
```

Then in the simulator it shows a location in the sea. I set the location to London in the simulator.

Comment: Run your application in Device it will show your current location.

Comment: Check this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661899/cant-set-zoom-level-on-mkmapview**

Comment: bhumeshwer katre is right @user1007522

Comment: I'm now on a real device. And still shows me the same location (my viewregion is bad or ?). And I also can't zoom in or out. Even that the documentation says the zooming is by default YES.

Comment: When I print out the current lat and longitude they are both 0.0 0.0

Comment: For the possibly 1,000th time: You cannot expect the user location to be ready to use immediately after setting showsUserLocation to YES.  You must read it in the didUpdateUserLocation delegate or only use if `userLocation.location` is not `nil`.  You _can_ get a simulated location in the simulator -- you don't need a device to test location services.  And at least up to iOS 7, you don't have to implement CLLocationManager if you are using showsUserLocation in MKMapView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do This:

```
@property  (strong, nonatomic)   CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

In viewdidload:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init] ;
self.locationManager.delegate = (id)self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation ;
[self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:10.0f] ;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And in your location manager

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = YourMapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
    zoomLocation.longitude= YourMapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;
    // 2
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*1609.344, 0.5*1609.344);
    // 3
    [YourMapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: But then the user can't zoom out and explore the map? I just want the zoom on start but let the user free to explore everything.

Comment: you add this code in your viewdidLoad. then user free to explore everything

Comment: Thanks for helping. Maybe worth mentioning: I'm having my map added as childviewcontroller. Not that It is therefore different but then again.

Comment: Try this updated code. and let me know if it works it works for me

Comment: You also have another question regarding resize your mapview. I Also post a shortcode for this. You can check this

Comment: Hi Daij-Djan, I just fulfil the requirement so i update this code.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to listen to changes for the user location. Because in the view didload the location isn't known.

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta  = 1; // Change these values to change the zoom
    span.longitudeDelta = 1;
    region.span = span;

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

and this in the viewdidload:

```
[self.mapView.userLocation addObserver:self
                            forKeyPath:@"location"
                               options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                               context:nil];
```

Comment: The MKMapView has a delegate method `didUpdateUserLocation` which you should use instead of KVO.  The delegate method was added in iOS 4.0.